# Ember not loading data in Chrome - DS.RESTAdapter has no method extend

Tags: google-chrome, ember.js, ember-data

I am calling

```
Hyena.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 11,
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend()
});
```

It doesn't work Chrome browser with a heap of errors like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'extend' of undefined` and `DS.RESTAdapter has no method extend`. Anyone have an idea why? It works fine in Safari and Firefox, but only loads 1 in 10 times in Chrome.

**Edit:** Adding one of the error outputs as requested:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'setup' ember.js?body=1:29481
Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend.setupEventDispatcher ember.js?body=1:29481
Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend.didBecomeReady ember.js?body=1:29453
DeferredActionQueues.flush ember.js?body=1:4901
Backburner.end ember.js?body=1:4591
Backburner.run ember.js?body=1:4630
Ember.run ember.js?body=1:5112
(anonymous function) ember.js?body=1:29201
fire jquery.js?body=1:3065
self.fireWith jquery.js?body=1:3177
jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js?body=1:434
completed jquery.js?body=1:105
```

Comment: What version of ED are you using?

Comment: `// Last commit: 07fbd58 (2013-06-01 14:33:06 -0400)` that should be more helpful?

Comment: Can you show the others errors? Maybe some previous error is the main cause of your problem ...

Comment: @MárcioRodriguesCorreaJúnior sure I added it to the question above.

Comment: I'm seeing similar things as well, however I can only reproduce in Chrome Canary.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was discovered in part thanks to @ahaurw01 - his mentioning that he could only reproduce in Chrome Canary lead me to check my Chrome version, which (for reason unknown) had 'dev' affixed to the version number. I re-downloaded Chrome from the website, removing that from the version, and it fixed the problem.

Still a concern for future releases of Chrome, but at least it's working for now.